# Loading xml from php/mysql for sencha architect

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax, extjs

Hi? I am trying to load an xml store in sencha architect using data from a mysql db.
    I   am constructing my xml as below;

```
//AFTER MYSQL QUERY

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

// display document in browser as plain text
 // for readability purposes
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// create root element
$root = $dom->createElement("stores");
$dom->appendChild($root);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//create child element
$storeitem = $dom->createElement("store");
$root->appendChild($storeitem);

// Company label
$company = $dom->createAttribute("c");
$storeitem->appendChild($company);

// company value
$companyValue = $dom->createTextNode($row['company']);
$company->appendChild($companyValue);

}
// save and display tree
echo $dom->saveXML();


//OUTPUT
<stores>
<store c="company1"/>
<store c="company2"/>
</stores>
```

The output is a structured xml. When I copy and paste this xml into an xml doc e.g
    test.xml and use it, it works perfectly. However, trying to use the echoed xml from php
     file does not work. Hope I made it clear. Please help.

Comment: you have to set the XML header for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 header ("content-type: text/xml");
```

dont use plain header

```
header ("content-type: text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

**->** Set the content type as "XML" : header("Content-type: text/xml");

**->** If your php program is to return an xml . Check wheather any space exists before or after your php tags.

```
(check wheather you have left spaces or something else here, if so remove it all)
<?php 
......
....
....
?>
(check wheather you have left spaces or something else here, if so remove it all)
```

Regards, [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in)